# Vue.js Dom is not updating on changing keys values of Object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, javascript-objects, vue-reactivity

I'm trying to create cart button and the issue is when a new item is added to cart if it's already exist the quantity of product should increase.

```
addToCart(index) {
  var item = this.sorted[index];
  var findProduct = this.cart.find((o) => o.Name === item.Name);
  if (findProduct) {
    item.quantity++;
   this.$set(item, 'quantity', item.quantity++)
    item.totalPrice = item.quantity * item.Price;
    return;
  } else {
    this.cart.push(item);
    // this property is not available in JSON file I'm setting it later
    item.quantity = 1;
    item.totalPrice = item.quantity * item.Price;
  }
},
```

and this is the data I have in JSON formate

```
{
    "Name": "plymouth volare custom",
    "Miles_per_Gallon": 19,
    "Cylinders": 6,
    "Displacement": 225,
    "Horsepower": 100,
    "Price": 3630,
    "Acceleration": 17.7,
    "Licensed": false,
    "Date_added": "1977-01-01",
    "Warehouse": "USA"
},
```

the issue is I don't have a **property** called **quantity** in the JSON file I'm pushing it in the code later you can that here

```
        item.quantity = 1
```

that's why when the quantity increases it don't update in DOM and don't show the reactivity

Adding manually a property quantity solve the issue but I can't add it manually. I have to make this thing reactive.

and you can check the live version of it here https://frankgarage.netlify.app/

Please help and thanks for your time

Comment: **item.quantity++** in $set, post increment does not take place immediately.

Comment: yeah I figured this out but I'm looking forward to solution Dear

Comment: after updating the items, update the dom using await Vue.$nextTick, hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the cart is what you are showing on the Dom
Then put manual assignment before the line where u push the item

```
addToCart(index) {
  var item = this.sorted[index];
  var findProduct = this.cart.find((o) => o.Name === item.Name);
  if (findProduct) {
    item.quantity++;
    item.totalPrice = item.quantity * item.Price;
   this.$set(item, 'quantity', item.quantity++)
    return;
  } else {
    item.quantity = 1;
    item.totalPrice = item.quantity * item.Price;
    this.cart.push(item);
    // this property is not available in JSON file I'm setting it later
  }
},
```

and after updating the items, update the dom using `Vue.$nextTick`, hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for you help but this is not working as well

Comment: you can check on live website try to add same product 3 4 times and than add another product and notice the cart icon.

Comment: check the uodate